# asp.net controls vs html element security?

Tags: asp.net, html

In general, If I have a choice when developing a web site to use html elements  or asp.net controls which one is better to use if my website is interactive with server side operations such as accessing database.
Is it more secure to use asp.net controls or does not matter.
On other words, is it more secure to use asp.net controls instead of html element to deliver data or receive data from/to server side or no differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference - ASP.NET controls will render as standard html elements because that's all browsers know how to display.

Answer (score 0):

HTML elements are simply markup for client-side pages. ASP.Net uses forms to post data back to a server and deliver content (including HTML markup) to users based on credentials, session variables, etc.. ASP.Net is not the only way of talking to a server (incl. a database), but it's a very good one, robust and very mature.

Comment: so what you mean that there are no differences in using html elements or asp.net controls in asp.net page regarding the security to interact with server side?

Comment: Security is something that happens between the server and the client, not within the page markup (html) itself.